# Insert data through a form is not working for my database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I know my html form works, so I'm not inserting all the tags, so this post looks cleaner:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<h1> Add Animal</h1>
<input type="text" name="P_ID#" placeholder="Pet ID">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Pet Name" placeholder="Pet Name">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="PType" placeholder="Pet Type">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Adoptable" placeholder="Adoptable? 1=yes||0=no">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Details_Medical" placeholder="Medical Details">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="Details_Personality" placeholder="Pet 
Personality">
<br/>
<input type="text" name="V_Name" placeholder="Vet Name">
<br/>

<input type="submit" value="ADD"> 
</form>
```

This is my database: it's connecting and recognizing the db, but it is not inserting for some reason. It worked for my other table in the database.

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
mysql_select_db("mydb");

if (mysqli_connect_error()){
echo 'ERROR';
}
else{
echo 'Connected';
}

if (!mysql_select_db('mydb'))
{
echo 'Database not selected';
}
else {echo ' DBSelected ';}

$a = $_POST['P_ID#'];
$b = $_POST['Pet Name'];
$c = $_POST['PType'];
$d = $_POST['Age'];
$h = $_POST['Adoptable'];
$e = $_POST['Details_Medical'];
$f = $_POST['Details_Personality'];
$g = $_POST['V_Name'];



$sql ="INSERT INTO `pet`(`P_ID#`, `Pet Name`, `PType`, `Age`, `Adoptable`, 
`Details_Medical`, `Details_Personality`, `V_Name`) 
VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d', '$h', '$e', '$f', '$g')"; 


if(!mysql_query($sql))
{echo ' NotInserted';}
else{echo 'Inserted';}


header("refresh:1; url=animal.php");

?>
```

I don't know where my problem is. This worked for another table I created. Pet_ID is a primary key, so I even made sure that I am not reinserting the same ID. My database is hosted in phpmyadmin

Comment: Is autocommit on? If not you'll have to commit manually for the changes to take effect

Comment: Just making suggestions for your code example. What you are doing here is susceptible to SQL injection and is bad practice in almost all cases. First, take peek at PHP's PDO for your database interactions - here is something: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo. More specifically: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared .  Mine as well do some light reading and do it the proper way the first time while you are solving your insert issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions, but it's still not inserting. I'm going to clean my code after I get the major tasks to work. Right now, I just want to know why my insert isn't working for this, even though it worked for a different table.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add a comment due to reputation, but if you're trying to...

> Right now, I just want to know why my insert isn't working for this, even though it worked for a different table.

Change

> mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
>
> mysql_select_db("mydb");

to

> $mysqli_connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","mydb");

Then change your error handling mysql_ functions to their mysqli_ counterparts on your $mysqli_connect variable.

Then change

> if(!mysql_query($sql))

to

> $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_connection, $sql);
>
> if(!$result){...

There's more to clean up but getting your connection and query into supported functions is the next step. The mysql_ functions throw an error in PHP7 and have been unsupported since PHP v5.5.0. You can't mix mysql_ and mysqli_